# How to set the width of the image in the following case?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image, where I want to set the width in javascript.

It is written in the following format, how do I set the width?

```
create("td",{colspan:"4",innerHTML:"<img src='"  + imagePath +  "Images/categoriesLogos.jpg'> style= 'width:900px'"},"space1");
```

Here imgePath is a variable. It picks up the image, but how do I assign the width?

Tried to use style the way it is shown in the code.

Comment: Have you tried using width attribute and also please format image tag correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline `style` tag is outside of your `img` tag.

Try this:

```
create("td",{colspan:"4",innerHTML:"<img src='"  + imagePath +  "Images/categoriesLogos.jpg' style= 'width:900px'>"},"space1");
```

Comment: Good spot - I didn't see that at first!

Comment: Awesome. Works. I missed that.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set it inline, your style attribute should be inside the element, before the closing tag `>`.